# Finding the difference between specific items in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting

I have a data object similar to this:

```
 const data = [
  {
      name: "john smith", created_at: "1616846400", description: "clocked in" //7am
  },
  {
    name: "john smith", created_at: "1616853600", description: "clocked Out" //9am
  },
  {
    name: "john smith", created_at: "1616857200", description: "clocked in" //10am
  },
  {
    name: "john smith", created_at: "1616875200", description: "clocked out" //3pm
  }
];
```

This is meant to represent a clock-in/clock-out punch sheet. **The goal is to find the total time this person has been clocked out during a work shift.**

the answer would be 1 hour. The user had clocked out at 9 am and returned at 10am and was not clocked out anymore until they left for the day.

I've tried this a few different ways, my most recent attempt looked like this

```
const data = [
  {
      name: "john smith", created_at: "1616846400", description: "clocked in"
  },
  {
    name: "john smith", created_at: "1616853600", description: "clocked Out"
  },
  {
    name: "john smith", created_at: "1616857200", description: "clocked in"
  },
  {
    name: "john smith", created_at: "1616875200", description: "clocked Out"
  }
];


let clockOuts = data.filter(function (e) {
    return e.description.split(" ").splice(0,2).join(" ") ===  "clocked Out"
  })

  let clockIns = data.filter(function (e) {
    return e.description.split(" ").splice(0,2).join(" ") ===  "clocked in"
  })


  var x = clockOuts.map(function(item, index) {

    if (clockIns[index] != null) {
      return Math.round(Math.abs(item.created_at - clockIns[index].created_at) / 60)
    } else {

      return Math.round(Math.abs(item.created_at * 0))
    }
  })//end clockins Map

  
  console.log(x)

  var sum = x.reduce(function(a, b){
    return a + b
  }, 0)

  console.log(sum)
```

Any help would be appreciated as I've hit a wall!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to be sure all items in a sequence, otherwise, nothing will work. That's why you need to group the elements.

To do that, I convert original data to a new array. The id fields are just to see the output easily, so they are not part of any functionality.

The goal here is to remove the items with IDs 3 and 6 because they are breaking the sequence.

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, name: 'john smith', created_at: '1616846400', description: 'clocked in' },
  { id: 2, name: 'john smith', created_at: '1616853600', description: 'clocked Out' },
  { id: 3, name: 'john smith', created_at: '1616857200', description: 'clocked in' },
  { id: 4, name: 'john smith', created_at: '1616867200', description: 'clocked in' },
  { id: 5, name: 'john smith', created_at: '1616875200', description: 'clocked Out' },
  { id: 6, name: 'john smith', created_at: '1616875200', description: 'clocked Out' },
  { id: 7, name: 'john smith', created_at: '1616867200', description: 'clocked in' },
  { id: 8, name: 'john smith', created_at: '1616875200', description: 'clocked Out' },
];


let sequence = {
  'clocked in': 'clocked Out',
  'clocked Out': 'clocked in',
};

let sequentialData = [];

const convertTime = x => {
  return Math.round(Math.abs(x[1].created_at - x[0].created_at) / 60)
}

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (
    data[i].description != 'clocked in' ||
    data[i + 1]?.description != sequence[data[i].description]
  ) {
    continue;
  }
  let pair = [data[i], data[i + 1]];
  sequentialData.push([convertTime(pair), ...pair]);
}

console.log(sequentialData)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! if it's not to much trouble could you explain the functionality of this line?  data[i + 1]?.description != sequence[data[i].description] 

im trying to soak up as much knowledge/understanding as possible!

Comment: It's comparing the descriptions of current and the next items. Let's say, if the current item's description is ''clocked in", sequence["clocked in"] will be "clocked Out" and if the next item's description is "clocked Out" they can create a pair like in and out. Otherwise, we need to move to the next index.

Answer (score 1):

`moment.js` will help alot:

```js
const data = [
  {name: "john smith", created_at: "1616846400", description:"clocked in"},
  {name: "john smith", created_at: "1616853600", description:"clocked Out"},
  {name: "john smith", created_at: "1616857200", description: "clocked in"},
  {name: "john smith", created_at: "1616875200", description: "clocked out"}
];

let clockedOutTimes = data.reduce((r,i,ix,o)=>{
   if (ix===0 || ix === o.length-1) return r;
   if (i.description.toLowerCase()==='clocked in') {
      let d = moment.unix(parseInt(i.created_at))
        .diff(moment.unix(parseInt(o[ix-1].created_at)),'hours');
      r=r+d
   }
   return r;
},0);

console.log(clockedOutTimes);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like this:

```
let clockOutDuration = 0

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const item = data[i]
    const nextItem = i < data.length - 1 ? data[i + 1] : null
    
    // clock out with clock in after
    if (item.description === 'clocked Out' && nextItem && nextItem.description === 'clocked in') {
        clockOutDuration += parseInt(nextItem.created_at) - parseInt(item.created_at)
    }
}
```

and then assuming the `created_at` time is in milliseconds, you can convert to your preferred unit of time.

`Math.floor(clockOutDuration / 1000)` for seconds, `Math.floor(clockOutDuration / 1000 / 60)` for minutes, etc.